# Complete game Szabo-Groszpeter, Kecskemet 1984

Tags: endgame, history, famous-players, knight-endgame

I'm looking for the complete game Szabo-Groszpeter, Kecskemet 1984. The following knight endgame was reached and White won eventually with the paradoxal move Kb8!! blocking his b-pawn on b7.

```
[fen "8/K5p1/1p5k/1P5p/P1n5/5N2/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Nd2 Nxd2 2.a5 bxa5 3.b6 Nf3 4.b7 Ne5 5.Kb8
```

I searched the complete game in various databases without success: chessgames.com, chess365 and chesstempo.

Comment: After various efforts I can not even find the complete game, it does not seem to be in chessbase or on the internet, the position appears in numerous books but not the complete game, maybe it was a playoff game ... in some books it is related as curiosity that the victory was assigned by committee when arriving at the 61 moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the game ended after a5. In Van Perlo's Endgame Tactics (Page 397 - ISBN 978-90-5691-494-3) it is described as following:"Here, at move 61, the game was interrupted, according to the rules applied at the time in the Hungarian Team Championship. The adjourned position was sent in for adjudication and the allgrandmasters committee declared the game a win for White."
He then give two main lines (main line with Kb8).

Comment: This would be rather disappointing. Nevertheless, thanks for your research! (+1 and accept)